# AWS Lambda, billed time longer than processing time

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, latency

In my Lambda function (Node.js), I measured the time from the start of my function to the end of my function which is about 1400 milliseconds. However, the billed duration lambda gives me is 2800 milliseconds.

Is this normal? What could be the reason for this high discrepancy (it's basically double)?

Here's the code I used to measure

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    let time = new Date();

    ... some logic runs ...

    console.log(`{new Date().getTime() - time.getTime()}`);
    callback(null, response);
}
```

Comment: What does `callback()` do? You're calling that *after* logging the time

Comment: In NodeJS when you call the Lambda callback function you are simply telling the Lambda service that it can shutdown the invocation once the NodeJS event loop is empty. If you want the Lambda function exit immediately, you need to set the following before calling the callback: `context.callbackWaitsForEmtpyEventLoop = false;`

Comment: THANK YOU! This had been plaguing me for days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All credit to Mark B as in comments.

Solution is to add the line:

```
context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
```

The reason is AWS Lambda by default, for Node.js deployments, will wait for the event loop to be empty before returning. Thus, if you can set the above line to prevent this from happening.

Comment: Note that you should also strive to understand what, in your code, makes this necessary... because unless you are leaving something on the event loop, it *will* be empty by the time you call the callback, and changing this value would have no impact.  Setting it without understanding why may be masking a bug.